# After re-creating user in phpmyadmin: "Access denied for user 'root'@'name_of_computer'" from c# applications

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

A bit of background: I have a small server on which I installed Windows and Wamp and is running a couple of databases with mysql server that are accessed in the local network through a couple of c# applications. The problem is that I configured the root user to be able to log in from any ip, because all my programs just used the root user to login and access the databases, so the inevitable thing happened and this morning my server got hacker and all my databases got emptied. At least I had a not so recent 3 months old backup.

What I did: I changed the host from % to localhost of the root user through phpmyadmin since I’m mostly unfamiliar with mysql’s console syntaxes, I noticed that when I did this using the webui it created a new user with the new host (localhost) so I deleted the previous root with the host %. I also changed the host of all other users to localhost, and created a new account (‘esmeralda’) that I copied from the root user but with the host % that I intend to use for my programs instead, and that I have with all privileges at the moment.

After doing this I can still log into phpmyadmin using the root user and use this user with my applications locally in the server, the problem is that after updating my applications with the new login information I get the error “access denied for user ‘esmeralda’@’name_of_pc’ (using password: YES)” when I run them either from another computer in the lan or from the localhost itself. The odd thing is that I’m even getting the same error running the application from the same server, I can see when I select a specific database that this new user appears under the privileges tab, and even after recreating the user and attempting some commands through the console that I saw in other threads I don’t get a different result. I guess I may be skipping some obvious important step, hopefully this is just an issue of changing the configuration of the new user.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, so this error message is also used for a wrong password, I didn't notice that the keyboard I use for my server had a bad numeric key until now.